# Reading multiple Emacs info files simultaneously

Tags: emacs

For reading programming (and other) documentation, the Emacs INFO mode is outstanding.  So outstanding that I would like to be able to read say, the Emacs Lisp info file and the org-mode info files simultaneously without traversing back up to the beginning of the info tree.  Either I've missed something obvious or I will need to hack some Emacs Lisp to achieve the goal.  And yet again, someone may have already cracked this nut.  So I guess my question is: what is the state of the practice for reading mulitple INFO files in Emacs simultaneously?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for the `'info` command (bound to <kbd>C-h i</kbd> by default), you'll find that you can easily create new `*info*` buffers with a numeric prefix.

```
C-u 1 C-h i
C-u 42 C-h i
```

That creates info buffers named `*info*<1>` and `*info*<42>`.

Documentation for the `'info` command is (emphasis mine):

> Enter Info, the documentation browser.
>   Optional argument file-or-node
>   specifies the file to examine; the
>   default is the top-level directory of
>   Info. Called from a program,
>   file-or-node may specify an Info node
>   of the form `(FILENAME)NODENAME'.
>   Optional argument buffer specifies the
>   Info buffer name; the default buffer
>   name is *info*.  If buffer exists,
>   just switch to buffer.  Otherwise,
>   create a new buffer with the top-level
>   Info directory.
>
> In interactive use, a non-numeric
>   prefix argument directs this command
>   to read a file name from the
>   minibuffer. **A numeric prefix argument
>   selects an Info buffer with the prefix
>   number appended to the Info buffer
>   name.**

Also, by default, in the `*info*` buffer, <kbd>M-n</kbd> is bound to `'clone-buffer`, which will create a new `*info*` buffer looking at the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you want to brew your own cup using emacs lisp there is the function "generate-new-buffer-name" available:

> This function returns a name that would be unique for a new buffer—but
>   does not create the buffer. It starts with starting-name, and produces
>   a name not currently in use for any buffer by appending a number
>   inside of ‘<…>’. It starts at 2 and keeps incrementing the number
>   until it is not the name of an existing buffer.

for example

```
(defun my-info-with-own-buffer ()
    (interactive)
    (info nil (generate-new-buffer-name "*info*")))
```

when invoked will open a fresh info buffer at the top directory node.